# Проверка запроса на ошибку-баг-повторный запрос

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(!mysql_query($query))
{ exit(mysql_error());}
```

как сделать чтобы происходила только проверка. а то запрос второй раз себя выполняет

Comment: у вас вероятно где-то еще стоит mysql_query($query)

Comment: А о чём вопрос-то? Откуда берётся второй запрос, если тут только один написан?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// подключение к базе
$link = mysql_connect("хост", "логин", "пароль") or die("SQL error: " . mysql_error());

// запросы к базе
$to_sql = "ваш sql запрос";
$sql_out = mysql_query ($to_sql, $link);
if (mysql_error()) print "SQL error: " . mysql_error();
```

Comment: Я бы все-таки делал так:

    //...
    $sql_out = mysql_query ($to_sql, $link);
    if (!$sql_out) print "SQL error: " . mysql_error();

Comment: Если, к примеру, по запросу SELECT ничего не найдено, то $sql_out будет false, а mysql_error() будет пустой.